# SQL IN statement for multiple columns Excel

Tags: mysql, vba, excel

Using VBA, Excel 2007, and the following connectionString:

```
"provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=myFile.xlsx; Extended Properties=Excel 12.0"
```

I'm trying to perform the following query `SELECT [col1], [col2] FROM [Sheet1$] WHERE ([col1], [col2]) IN ((val1, val2), (val3, val4), (val5, val6))`

Alas, VBA errors specifying that it doesn't like the comma in the query expression.

Is there any syntax change I could perform to make this query run?
Or another query that would do the same thing?

Below is the surrounding code per request

```
Sub testQuery()
   Dim conStr As String, sql As String
   conStr = "provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\me\Desktop\QueryMe.xlsx; Extended Properties=Excel 12.0"
   sql = "SELECT col1, col2 FROM [Sheet1$] WHERE (col1, col2) IN (('val1', 'val2'), ('val3', 'val4'), ('val5', 'val6'))"
   Dim objCon As Object, objRS As Object
   Set objCon = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
   Set objRS = CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")

   objCon.Open con
   objRS.Open sql, con
   objRS.Close
   objCon.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Please post your actual code.

Comment: Have you tried `where (col1 = 'val1' and col2='val2') or (col1='val3' and col2='val4') and ...`?

Comment: @zfus I had not, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to get away with this:

```
sql = "SELECT col1, col2 FROM [Sheet1$] WHERE col1+col2 IN ('val1val2','val3val4','val5val6')"
```

Comment: This query will return different results, such as rows with ('val1', 'val4'), and is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: @Greg are you looking for combos within the two columns like col1 has both `val1' and `val2` OR it has both `val3` and `val4`?

Comment: Looking to return only rows which have a listed combination of values. I.e. (col1 = 'val1' AND col2 = 'val2') OR (col1 = 'val3' AND col2 = 'val4') ...

Comment: @Greg Oh, I see. I updated the answer. I **think** you might be able to do what I put in the answer. Not completely sure though. Not the most elegant, but if the text is short enough, it might suit you without too much trouble.

Comment: Clever solution. I'd expect this to be slower than zfus' solution? It is certainly a more concise sql statement.

Comment: @Greg I believe it would be slower, yes. Text manipulation is pretty expensive. But I'm glad this worked out for you! cheers!